# convert json string into array or object

Tags: c#, json, webforms

I get some json data form the web which is like:

```
[{
  "pk": 1,
  "model": "stock.item",
  "fields": {
    "style": "f/s",
    "name": "shirt",
    "color": "red",
    "sync": 1,
    "fabric_code": "0012",
    "item_code": "001",
    "size": "34"
  }
}, {
  "pk": 2,
  "model": "stock.item",
  "fields": {
    "style": "febric",
    "name": "Trouser",
    "color": "red",
    "sync": 1,
    "fabric_code": "fabric code",
    "item_code": "0123",
    "size": "44"
  }
}]
```

How can i use it in the C# winforms desktop application. I already get this data in the form of string.
Edit:

I also try to use this way..

```
JavaScriptSerializer ss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
object itm = ss.DeserializeObject(responseFromServer);
```

It returns 'System.Object[]' but i also dont know that how i can use this.
All types of answer are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I think what your after is [JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation for JavaScriptSerializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer?view=netframework-4.8) specifies that for your purpose you should use [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) instead.

However, if you prefer to continue to use `JavaScriptSerializer` you need to do the following:

```
JavaScriptSerializer ss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var itm = ss.DeserializeObject(responseFromServer);
```

The StackOverflow thread [difference-between-var-and-object-in-c-sharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552881/difference-between-var-and-object-in-c-sharp) describes how using `var` implicitly types the variable, so that it's easier to work with, where-as your code uses `object`, which strongly types it to an object.