# var vs Object in C#

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between “var” and “object” in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552881/difference-between-var-and-object-in-c)

I would like to know the difference between var and object.

When to use Var and when to use Object.

Pros and cons of using them.

Comment: Looks extremely similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552881/difference-between-var-and-object-in-c

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`var` is just shorthand for "let the compiler pick the right variable type for me" (compile-time type-inference is the more exact term).

`object`, on the other hand, is a specific type; all other reference types derive from `object`, so you can assign anything to a variable of type `object`.

Comment: Unless it's a primitive, in which case it must be boxed before being assigned into the `Object` reference.

Comment: I think something that should be added to the selected answer is that if you use <code>var</code> then as @Ben Voigt said, you can do things to the object stored in var without having to cast it.

Answer (score 13):

`var` is the answer when you find yourself asking, do I really have to type that long type name twice, in e.g.:

```
Dictionary<string, Func<List<Func<int, int, double>>, IEnumerable<Tuple<double, string>>>> myDict = new Dictionary<string, Func<List<Func<int, int, double>>, IEnumerable<Tuple<double, string>>>>();
```

Why no friend, you don't.  Use `var` instead:

```
var myDict = new Dictionary<string, Func<List<Func<int, int, double>>, IEnumerable<Tuple<double, string>>>>();
```

Now `myDict` really is a `Dictionary<string, Func<List<Func<int, int, double>>, IEnumerable<Tuple<double, string>>>>`, so you can add things to it, enumerate it, etc.

If you declared it as `object` you couldn't do any operations with it that are provided by `Dictionary`, only the ones valid for all objects.

Comment: I'd love to see that code in action.

Comment: Your computer running Windows?  j/k.

I made up that particular type but I was trying pretty hard to use types that might actually be combined together.

Comment: That has to be the most obnoxious code snippet ever :)

Comment: And also the most contrived... but while it IS exaggerated, it isn't by very much.

Comment: I think the worst I've ever done was a Dictionary<int, List<Dictionary<SomePrimitive, SomeClass>>>, but if I remember right, it was built and consumed a little at a time, so I didn't see all that at once.

Answer (score 6):

var is still strongly typed but with object you will have to cast everything.

Answer (score 5):

```
var foo = "Hello, I am a string!";
// foo is a string, so this compiles
var fooCharArray = foo.ToCharArray(); 

object bar = foo;
// bar is not a string, so this does not compile
var barCharArray = bar.ToCharArray();
```

In the first example, the compiler knows that `foo` is a string and so we can call string methods on `foo`.

In the second example, we "upcast" the string `foo` to an object.  Now the compiler does not know (because it shouldn't know!) that `bar` is actually a string, and we cannot call string methods on `bar`.  The compiler will not allow implicit downcasting from an object (or any base type) to a derived type (such as `System.String`).  Its part of compile time type safety rules.