# ReSharper: Visual Studio : warning use VAR

Tags: c#, var

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [What's the point of the var keyword?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209199/whats-the-point-of-the-var-keyword)
>   [ReSharper and var](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737835/resharper-and-var)

I am using ReSharper Tool for code cleanup.
it always prompt to use `var`   instated of actual type name.
it looks good but is there any advantages are there?

Examples:

when we use

`Dictionary<long, Profile> dicProfile = new Dictionary<long, Profile>`

it prompt to convert it to ::

```
 var dicProfile = new Dictionary<long, Profile>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite a few resharper options are opinion based.

- Use var instead of actual type name.
- whatever == true is redundant.
- this. is redundant
- etc..

You can turn them all of in the resharper settings, or at the time it prompts you.

Comment: ctually they agree on their blog somewhere that this one rule iS VERY disputed. I hate it ;)

Comment: I think 'var' is one of the better language improvements as of late. This is nonsense: Dictionary<MyType<Something>, IEnumerable<Something>> stuff = new Dictionary<MyType<Something>, IEnumerable<Something>>(); var makes it better.

Comment: I love var - for anonymous types. I normally always hardcode all variables.

Comment: i suppose the question is why is var preferred to actual data type.

Answer (score 3):

ReSharper has two types of warnings when the type can be inferred. You get a squiggly line when the type of your variable is exactly the same as the instantiated type:

```
Dictionary<long, Profile> dicProfile = new Dictionary<long, Profile>();
```

And you get a shorter underscored line when the variable's type is a base class of the instantiated type (like the `IDictionary<>` interface in this case):

```
IDictionary<long, Profile> dicProfile = new Dictionary<long, Profile>();
```

Whether you want this, is personal preference. I like this feature, especially in the first case, because it seems redundant to me to explicitly declare the type of a variable when it can be inferred.

If you don't want this you can turn this of by going here:

ReSharper -> Options -> Code Inspection -> Inspection Severity -> Language Usage Upportunities -> Use 'var' keyword when initializer explicitly declares type

And here:

ReSharper -> Options -> Code Inspection -> Inspection Severity -> Language Usage Upportunities -> Use 'var' keyword when possible

Answer (score 0):

Its up to you, if you want to follow what re sharper suggestion.

But Re-sharper really help .net developer to:

```
clean you codes 
promotes coding standards
fix syntax/refactor
remove  redundancy object declarationy using var: 

Object data = new Object to  
var data = new Object()

 And Many More..
```

[Same Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221175/var-vs-object-in-c)

Regards